# Команда print не выводит русские буквы

Tags: python, кодировка

Почему не выводятся русские буквы:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
famile = (u"Иванов", u"Петров", u"Сидоров")
print famile

>>> (u'\u0418\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432', u'\u041f\u0435\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0432', u'\u0421\u0438\u0434\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0432')
```

Comment: Потому что пора переходить на 3й питон 8-)

Comment: @andreymal `print u'[%s]' % ', '.join(['"%s"' % item for item in mylist])` - помогло

Comment: @Flowneee: Дело не в версии Питона. Прочтите мой комментарий к вопросу-дубликату.